# navigator.userAgent does not contains .NET Framework version

Tags: javascript, .net

I knew that I could use `navigator.userAgent` to check if .NET Framework is installed on client machine. Now, it seems User-Agent does not include that information anymore.

In my case, this is the string: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36`

How can I accomplish that task using JavaScript? is there another method or property I can use?